# fstab can't find (mount) USB drive - any ideas?

Tags: mount, fstab, uuid

I just cannot get fstab to mount a drive!

Have added entry in fstab:  `UUID=CC89C1B5  /media/USB vfat nosiud,nodev 0 0`

When I run `sudo mount -a` (to mount all in fstab)
it gives error: "`can't find "UUID=CC89C1B5"`"

blkid confirms this is correct UUID

Manual mount of drive with `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /media/USB` works fine.

Any ideas? I've been going in circles!

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo blkid`; I think there should be a hyphen in the middle of the UUID of FAT file systems.

Comment: All my UUIDs are in lower case, e.e

Comment: How exactly did you run blkid? You may need to use `blkid -c /dev/null` to ensure that it is not returning a previously cached UUID

Comment: Did you create a mount point /media/USB? Typo? nosiud s/b:nosuid And external drives mounted with fstab should have extra parameters. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#Automount_with_systemd
Either systemd-automount or autofs can be used. You also may want nofail.

Comment: Update:  I've found that it works fine if I use the LABEL option instead of the UUID. Not sure why it doesn't like UUID.

Comment: I tried numerous permutations with the hypen, without it, lower case, uppercase.

Comment: mount point was created already as /media/USB - and it worked manually also.

Comment: Is mounting via fstab working for you now? If not, Please run `sudo blkid -c /dev/null`; Edit the original question to show us the output. Indent each line 4 spaces to render the output as `code`. When we get this information, we have better chances to really help you. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Try lowercasing your UUID. `UUID=cc89c1b5`

Comment: blkid - /dev/null  gives no output.
blkid gives:
/dev/sda1: LABEL="HD2TB" UUID="A6C1-68C7" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="exfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="faa0dv14-1a06-47a4-936a-a8dce7207ce1"    Note this is a different disk from previous, but same situation.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine using LABEL instead of UUID.